Is there a non-formal definition of a polynomial?
A polynomial function in one variable is a function $f$ such that $$f(x) = \sum_n a_nx^n.$$ This definition is purely formal in that it gives a form for a polynomial function, but no characteristics.  In contrast, definitions for other things (such as linear function, differentiable function) don't give a particular form or template, but rather a set of properties.
Is there a similar definition for a polynomial function? A polynomial function is a function that...
One candidate might be: is analytic, defined everywhere, and has a finite number of zeroes.  However, this would not exclude $e^x$ which has zero zeroes, just like $f(x) = k$.

See https://mathoverflow.net/a/92394/532

Alternatively, you could seek a property that's unique to the set of polynomial functions in one variable $x$, e.g. it's the smallest set containing the zero function that also contains all antiderivatives of its elements.

I assume you'll allow us to interpret them as being over any field? And along those lines, you should probably specify any limitations on the $a_n$.

Have you already reviewed candidate definitions you can find online like at ProofWiki? If so, could you explain why those definitions (e.g. the universal property definition) don't meet your needs?

Answers need to be posted as answers, not as comments, and not as edits to the original question.

There are many options, as you've already noted. Which one, if any, is relevant to a particular situation depends on the situation. Another option specific to $\mathbb{C}$ is that a function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial exactly if it is

holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, and
meromorphic at infinity, meaning that $f \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$ is meromorphic in a neighborhood of $z = 0$.

The order of the pole at infinity (meaning the order of the pole of $f \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$ at $z = 0$) is the degree of the polynomial.
